# Same Foreign key column referring to 2 separate primary key of 2 table

Tags: mysql, database

I'm new to DB design.

I have got 3 tables. jobseeker, employers and login.

I want to have the same login page for both type of users( jobseeker and employer). On Login, I want to first validate the credentials from login table, and identify the role. Based on the role I can go either to jobseeker table or employer table to fetch further details about the user.

On SignUp/Registration I want to fill up jobseeker/employer first and then update login table.
On user Login, I want to first refer to login table then go to jobseeker/employer table.

```
CREATE TABLE `jobseeker` (
  `jobseeker_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `jobseeker_username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`jobseeker_id`,`jobseeker_username`),
);

CREATE TABLE `employer` (
  `employer_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `employer_username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employer_id`,`employer_username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `employer_username_UNIQUE` (`employer_username`),
);

CREATE TABLE `login` (
  `login_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login_username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `login_password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `login_role` enum('J','E') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`login_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `login_username_UNIQUE` (`login_username`),
  CONSTRAINT `login_username_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`login_username`) REFERENCES `jobseeker` (`jobseeker_username`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `login_username_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`login_username`) REFERENCES `employer` (`employer_username`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Now the problem is , when a user signup as jobseeker, the jobseeker table gets populated, a attempt is made to update the login table accordingly. But I'm facing a issue there. The login table tries to look for the same username in employer table due to the foreign key restriction. I have read about conditional foreign key, not sure how to use it exactly, and what are the pros and cons of it.

Comment: Maybe you can make a foreign key from the employer and jobseeker table to the login table instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two *1-0..1* relations here with `login` as the 1-side (the mandatory side) and `employer` and `jobseeker` on the 1..0-side (optional side). These relations are modelled by putting or foreign key on the optional side referencing the primary key of the mandatory side and additionally putting a unique constraint on it. So your foreign keys are on the wrong side. You could also add some kind of discriminator field on login to determine which type of login this is, but this is not strictly necessary. You only have to take care that you create exactly one of the child entries.